# (Basic) How to fix with React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to connect my react page to my node server which is up and running. When I try to fetch the data, it calls it properly, but has problems displaying it to the react front page.

I tried altering the state to no avail.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    employees: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProducts();
  }

  getProducts = _ => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3003/employees')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({data}) => {
        console.log("response" + data)
        console.log("response: " + data[0].id + " " + data[1].first_name)
      })
      .then(response => this.setState({ employees: response.data }))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  renderEmployee = ({id, first_name}) => <div key = {id}></div>


  render() {
    const { employees } = this.state;
    return(
      <div className = "App"> 
        <p>test 1</p>
          {employees.map(this.renderEmployee)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

'http://localhost:3003/employees' returns:
{"data":[{"id":1,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"},{"id":2,"first_name":"Johnathan","last_name":"G"},{"id":3,"first_name":"Jenny","last_name":"S"}]}

BUT when trying to call it from react

```
.then(({data}) => {
        console.log("response" + data)
        console.log("response: " + data[0].id + " " + data[1].first_name)
      })
```

I get the following outputs from the console.logs above:

```
response[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 
response: 1 Johnathan App
```

and the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably slim down the code like this:

```
 getProducts = _ => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3003/employees')
      .then(response => this.setState({ employees: response.data }))

  }
```

Comment: to test it, inside your render function `console.log(this.state.employees)`

Comment: when I tested it, I got an empty array and an undefined value. It seems like the data isn't loading on properly

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues:

1. You don't need another level of {data} after extracting the response to json object.
2. Render function accepts 'a employee' item and should be used for referencing properties.

   class App extends Component {
       state = {
         employees: []
       }

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
     this.getProducts();
   }

   getProducts = () => {
     fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then((data) => {
           this.setState({ employees: data })
       })
       .catch(err => console.error(err))
   }

   renderEmployee = (employee: any) => <div key={employee.id}> {employee.employee_name}</div>


   render() {
     const { employees } = this.state;
     return(
       <div className = "App"> 
         <p>test 1</p>
           {employees.map(this.renderEmployee)}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I made the changes you recommended and got a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" I used conditional rendering like so "           {employees && employees.map(this.renderEmployee)}" and that got rid of the error but none of the data is showing up. I don't think that it's loading properly